# How do I setup a virtualbox server with a static ip on real server?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-server-2008, ubuntu-server, static-ip

I have dedicate server run Windows server 2008 Standard with 2 static IP is: 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2.

And I have setup virtualbox server run Ubuntu Server 13 on Windows server. How I can set static IP 1.1.1.1 for virtual server?

Answer (score 0):

Bridge the virtual network adapter and assign whatever address you like in the VM operating system.